# Is it possible to set one div to left of ahother if the latter has float:none?

Tags: css, css-float, html

It 's a very simple question... at the first glance. And not so simple at the second. :-/

There are two divs: #content and #sidebar (in this order!) which are contained in a div #main. The #content div may have a very long tables or strings, and must not crop them or increase width of itself, so overflow:hidden and any kinds of flow is not allowed. The #sidebar div may be higher then #content. The #main div must have a height of the highest div inside, so "position: absolute; top: 0;" for #sidebar is not a solution.

The question: is it possible to set a #sidebar div to the left of #content div while not using any kind of float for #content and keeping all divs totally inside of #main?

I have made an illustration here: http://jsfiddle.net/dZLmu/

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="content">
        <p>It's a content area. It can contain a very long
            tables or strings which must not be cropped by
            overflow: hidden and must no extend a width of
            div itself. Something like that:</p>
        <p>WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW</p>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <p>It's a sidebar.</p>
        <p>It can be higher then content area.</p>
        <p>Menu item #.</p>
        <p>Menu item #.</p>
        <p>Menu item #.</p>
        <p>Menu item #.</p>
        <p>Menu item #.</p>
        <p>Menu item #.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main {
    background-color: silver;
    margin: 0 auto;
    widht: 500px;
    #position: relative;
}

#content {
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

#sidebar {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    #position: absolute;
    #top: 0;
}

#clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: By setting absolute positions for the `#sidebar` and `#content` you should be able to make them adjacent with no problems. I would suggest that you set both elements as `height:100%` so that the smaller of the two will match the larger. You should also consider using new CSS3 elements like `<header>`, `<aside>`, `<main>` and `<footer>`.

Comment: The answer really depends on what you are OK with and some of the reasoning behind not using floats. Can you not set a specific width for the content area? Or simply use percentages? What sort of browser support do you need? Can you use flexbox, or calc(), for example?

Comment: This is using DevlshOne's recommendations: http://jsfiddle.net/Morlock0821/Tdwjx/1/

Comment: @DevlshOne: In that case I have to set a certain height for the #main div? It's not always possible. And I still have to support 8% of our visitors with IE 8. :-(

Comment: @robooneus: Yes, a #content div width is (#main - #sidebar) and may be specified in px or %. So pity I still have to support IE8. :-(

Comment: @PedroEstrada: But if you remove explicit height of the #main div, all things collapsed. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dZLmu/3/)**

**css**

```
#main {
    background-color: silver;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:table;
}
#content {
    background-color: green;  
    display:table-cell;
    word-break:break-all;

}

#sidebar {
    background-color: red; 
    width: 100px;  
   display:table-cell;

}

#clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
```

**[demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/dZLmu/4/)**

Comment: There are two drawbacks for this solution: "word-break" doesn't work for a long tables inside the #content and layout itself can't be "adaptive" for using on a small screens.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest thing would simply be to apply specific widths to both the `#sidebar` and `#content` elements, either as a percentage or pixel width (if you give the wrapper a set width). If you cannot specify a width for `#content`, but want to use floats, you can use calc().

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dZLmu/2/)

```
#content {
    float:right;
    width:calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

Where you simply subtract the width of the `#sidebar` element. This is not compatible with IE8, however. Check [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc%28%29)

*This is simply meant as an alternative to other answers, based on what might fit the actual use-case*

Answer (score 1):

A [possible solution](http://jsfiddle.net/dZLmu/11/):

```
#content {
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#sidebar {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: -100%;
    position: relative; 
}
```

What happens here? First, setting `display:inline-block` to `#content` changes the formatting context where `#content` lives from block to inline (containers becomes one-line text with one big `word` that contains the entire block of content inside). Then, we limit its *outer* height and add a transparent border that emulates margin and holds the place for the floating column. And last, we make the floating div take no horizontal place (by setting large negative margin) and change its effective z-index by setting relative position to it.

But wouldn't it easier just to swap two divs in the source code, so that sidebar comes first?

Comment: Very interesting solution! I'll thoroughly test it at home. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The usual method when not using floats is to use **display: inline-block:** http://www.jsfiddle.net/zygnz/1/

**CSS Code**

```
.container div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="container">
<div id="content">
        <p>It's a content area. It can contain a very long
            tables or strings which must not be cropped by
            overflow: hidden and must no extend a width of
            div itself. Something like that:</p>
        <p>WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW</p>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <p>It's a sidebar.</p>
        <p>It can be higher then content area.</p>
        <p>Menu item #.</p>
        <p>Menu item #.</p>
        <p>Menu item #.</p>
        <p>Menu item #.</p>
        <p>Menu item #.</p>
        <p>Menu item #.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do note its limitations though: There is a additional space after the first bloc - this is because the two blocks are now essentially inline elements, like a and em, so whitespace between the two counts. This could break your layout and/or not look nice, and I'd prefer not to strip out all whitespaces between characters for the sake of this working.

Floats are also more flexible, in most cases.

Setting **display attribute to table-cell** also works
    display:table-cell;

Hope this Helps